# MySQL and Apache are running out of memory

Tags: mysql, apache-2.4, memory, mariadb, outofmemoryerror

Can you help me how can I figure which SQL query makes my MySQL running out of memory?

So, running dmesg command in console, I get following result:

```
[root@dmzemf httpd]# dmesg -T | grep 'Out of memory'
[Tue Apr 16 11:21:19 2019] Out of memory: Kill process 7522 (mysqld) score 185 or sacrifice child
[Tue Apr 16 11:23:26 2019] Out of memory: Kill process 11628 (mysqld) score 108 or sacrifice child
[Tue Apr 16 11:25:36 2019] Out of memory: Kill process 11847 (mysqld) score 109 or sacrifice child
[Tue Apr 16 11:25:36 2019] Out of memory: Kill process 12010 (httpd) score 106 or sacrifice child
[Tue Apr 16 11:53:14 2019] Out of memory: Kill process 12070 (mysqld) score 116 or sacrifice child
[Tue Apr 16 11:53:14 2019] Out of memory: Kill process 12008 (httpd) score 99 or sacrifice child
[Tue Apr 16 12:04:01 2019] Out of memory: Kill process 13530 (mysqld) score 127 or sacrifice child
[Tue Apr 16 12:04:01 2019] Out of memory: Kill process 13554 (mysqld) score 128 or sacrifice child
[Tue Apr 16 12:04:01 2019] Out of memory: Kill process 13563 (mysqld) score 128 or sacrifice child
[Tue Apr 16 14:01:15 2019] Out of memory: Kill process 18465 (mysqld) score 117 or sacrifice child
[Tue Apr 16 14:01:15 2019] Out of memory: Kill process 18666 (httpd) score 116 or sacrifice child
[Tue Apr 16 14:07:07 2019] Out of memory: Kill process 20734 (mysqld) score 120 or sacrifice child
[Tue Apr 16 14:07:07 2019] Out of memory: Kill process 20683 (httpd) score 75 or sacrifice child
[Tue Apr 16 14:07:11 2019] Out of memory: Kill process 21072 (httpd) score 100 or sacrifice child
[root@dmzemf httpd]#
```

I checked also file /var/log/mariadb.log:

```
[root@dmzemf mariadb]# tail mariadb.log 
Version: '5.5.60-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
190416 14:01:13 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
190416 14:01:13 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
190416 14:01:13 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
190416 14:01:13 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
190416 14:01:13 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
190416 14:01:13 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
190416 14:01:13 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.60-MariaDB) starting as process 20734 ...
190416 14:01:13 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
190416 14:01:13 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
190416 14:01:13 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer...
190416 14:01:14  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
190416 14:01:15 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.59-MariaDB-38.11 started; log sequence number 9910582483
190416 14:01:15 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
190416 14:01:15 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
190416 14:01:15 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
190416 14:01:15 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.60-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
190416 14:07:06 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
190416 14:07:06 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
190416 14:07:07 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.60-MariaDB) starting as process 21142 ...
190416 14:07:08 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
190416 14:07:08 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
190416 14:07:08 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
190416 14:07:08 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
190416 14:07:08 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
190416 14:07:08 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
190416 14:07:08 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer...
190416 14:07:10  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
190416 14:07:11 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.59-MariaDB-38.11 started; log sequence number 9913403499
190416 14:07:11 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
190416 14:07:11 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
190416 14:07:11 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
190416 14:07:11 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.60-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
```

File /var/log/httpd/error_log returns next:

```
[root@dmzemf httpd]# tail error_log
[Sun Apr 14 03:17:16.513647 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1501] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.4.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Apr 14 03:17:16.513667 2019] [core:notice] [pid 1501] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Mon Apr 15 11:26:38.754999 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1501] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Mon Apr 15 11:26:39.863554 2019] [core:notice] [pid 2894] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Mon Apr 15 11:26:39.957750 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2894] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.4.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Apr 15 11:26:39.957774 2019] [core:notice] [pid 2894] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Tue Apr 16 08:32:42.820348 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2894] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Tue Apr 16 08:32:43.949798 2019] [core:notice] [pid 1909] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Tue Apr 16 08:32:44.056357 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1909] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.4.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 16 08:32:44.056391 2019] [core:notice] [pid 1909] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Tue Apr 16 13:21:09.454338 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1909] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Tue Apr 16 13:21:10.655994 2019] [core:notice] [pid 18170] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Tue Apr 16 13:21:10.934372 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18170] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.4.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 16 13:21:10.934395 2019] [core:notice] [pid 18170] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[root@dmzemf httpd]#
```

Also, maybe can help content of the file /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf

```
#
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
#
# See the examples of server my.cnf files in /usr/share/mysql/
#

# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 128M
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
#innodb_log_file_size = 128M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M


# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]

# This group is only read by MariaDB-5.5 servers.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MariaDB of different versions,
# use this group for options that older servers don't understand
[mysqld-5.5]

# These two groups are only read by MariaDB servers, not by MySQL.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# you can put MariaDB-only options here
[mariadb]

[mariadb-5.5]
```

For sure, there are some PHP scripts that makes this problem, but I cannot identify them... Can you help me please?

** UPDATE **

Huh, I didn't tell that problem is most probably caused by PHP application that works with table that have more that 20 columns...

Output of sar -u 1 10 command, looks like this:

For page that works:

```
[root@dmzemf ~]# sar -u 1 10
Linux 3.10.0-693.11.1.el7.x86_64 (dmzemf.domain.com)      04/18/2019      _x86_64_        (2 CPU)

09:24:20 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
09:24:21 AM     all      0.00      0.00      0.50      0.00      0.00     99.50
09:24:22 AM     all      0.00      0.00      0.50      0.00      0.00     99.50
09:24:23 AM     all      0.50      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     99.50
09:24:24 AM     all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
09:24:25 AM     all     24.00      0.00      3.50      0.00      0.00     72.50
09:24:26 AM     all     46.73      0.00      4.02      0.50      0.00     48.74
09:24:27 AM     all      1.01      0.00      1.51      0.00      0.00     97.49
09:24:28 AM     all      1.50      0.00      0.50      0.00      0.00     98.00
09:24:29 AM     all      0.00      0.00      0.50      0.00      0.00     99.50
09:24:30 AM     all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
Average:        all      7.37      0.00      1.10      0.05      0.00     91.48
[root@dmzemf ~]#
```

For page that causes problems:

```
[root@dmzemf ~]# sar -u 1 10
Linux 3.10.0-693.11.1.el7.x86_64 (dmzemf.domain.com)      04/18/2019      _x86_64_        (2 CPU)

09:26:03 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
09:26:04 AM     all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
09:26:05 AM     all     46.27      0.00      4.48      0.00      0.00     49.25
09:26:06 AM     all     47.24      0.00      2.51      0.00      0.00     50.25
09:26:07 AM     all      7.00      0.00      2.00      0.00      0.00     91.00
09:26:08 AM     all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
09:26:09 AM     all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
09:26:10 AM     all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
09:26:11 AM     all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
09:26:12 AM     all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
09:26:13 AM     all      0.50      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     99.50
Average:        all     10.12      0.00      0.90      0.00      0.00     88.98
[root@dmzemf ~]#
```

Also, top part of top command looks like this:

```
Tasks: 180 total,   2 running, 178 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 27.0 us,  2.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 70.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  3882072 total,   182316 free,  1998020 used,  1701736 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  2097148 total,  1780112 free,   317036 used.  1472304 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                 
27141 apache    20   0  821852 473448   4424 R  49.2 12.2   0:03.45 httpd                                   
28289 mysql     20   0  971048 131304   8272 S  10.0  3.4   0:01.06 mysqld                                  
28531 emf       20   0  162040   2368   1592 R   0.3  0.1   0:00.09 top                                     
    1 root      20   0  201860   4860   2932 S   0.0  0.1 104:36.02 systemd                                 
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:12.95 kthreadd                                
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:17.60 ksoftirqd/0                             
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H                            
    7 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:02.86 migration/0                             
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh                                  
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0 118:06.00 rcu_sched                               
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   2:47.77 watchdog/0                              
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   3:00.40 watchdog/1                              
   12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:02.30 migration/1                             
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:20.28 ksoftirqd/1                             
   15 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H                            
   17 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs
```

I hope that this can give us clue what can we do in this case... Thank you in advance!

Comment: How much memory do you have?!

Comment: Can you post the output of 'top' and run 'sar -u 1 10' also (requires sysstat package), post output of that also?

Comment: Sure, plese take a look in updated part of my primary post.

Comment: If you can put in a `memory_get_peak_usage(true)` call at the end of your scripts and log the usage plus url, then you may get a closer look at the memory usage of the scripts.

Comment: Also see http://drib.tech/programming/get-real-amount-memory-allocated-php

Comment: I'm voting to move this to the database administrator's stack exchange, though with some hesitation. But the basic question seems to be "how do I figure out which query is the problem and how can I then improve it"; and that falls in their area of expertise rather than ServerFault's.

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this issue is to set memory allocation limits in way that system under full load cant take all memory of machine.

The problem is caused by fact that your software is trying to allocate more memory than is available. If you set max memory for db and db reaches 100% usage it will slowdown the db but it wont cause OOM on system. Same for apache.

Comment: In few places, in php code, i have line: ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); could it be the reason for issue?

Comment: @user48058 - Why use -1?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have enough resources on server http and mysql are having top oom score, to check what queries taking long time and resources, take **SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST** output after every 5 min, it will help to identify the query. For http oom check the number of connection at that point of time, since I am not sure about your workload please check your mpm too, from logs I can see you are using prefork which may be not best option for your kind of workload, kindly review.